# How come the ramp function be the primitive of the Heavyside function, since it is not differentiable at $0$?

Tags: integration, derivatives

In my engineering classes, I recall seeing that the integral of the Heavyside function is the ramp function. The Heavyside function is defined as $H(t) = 1$ for $t\ge 0$ and $H(t) = 0$ for $t<0$. And the ramp function $R$ is $R(t)=t$ for $x \ge 0$ and $R(t) = 0$ for $t<0$.

However, one can clearly see that the ramp function is not differentiable at $t=0$. It therefore violates the definition we see in highschool « the primitive $F$ of a function $f$ is such as $F'=f$ ».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can well believe that your high school teacher told you that the primitive $F$ of any integrable function $f$ satisfies $F'=f$. But as you have discovered, the reality is more nuanced than this. In order for your high school teacher's statement to hold, we must either impose conditions on $f$, or else we must relax the statement.

**Version 1: when $f$ is continuous.**

> Let $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Then $f$ is [Riemann integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral). Let $F: [a, b] \to \mathbb R$ be the primitive of $f$, i.e. $F(t) := \int_a^t f(x) dx$. Then for all $t \in (a, b)$, $F$ is differentiable at $t$ and $F'(t) = f(t)$.

Most of the functions you encountered at high school are continuous. For example, $f(t) = t^2$ and $f(t) = \sin t$ are continuous. For all continuous $f$, this theorem tells you that the derivative of the primitive of $f$ is equal to $f$ everywhere.

However, the Heaviside function is *not* continuous, so this theorem is not applicable to the Heaviside function.

**Version 2: when $f$ is Lebesgue integrable.**

> Let $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb R$ be [Lebesgue integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration). Let $F: [a, b] \to \mathbb R$ be the primitive of $f$, i.e. $F(t) := \int_a^t f(x) dx$. Then, for *almost all* $t \in (a, b)$, $F$ is differentiable at $t$ and $F'(t) = f(t)$.

You may not be familiar with Lebesgue integrable functions, but suffice it to say that Lebesgue integrable functions include quite a broad class of functions. For example:

- All Riemann integrable functions are Lebesgue integrable. This includes continuous functions, as well as piecewise continuous functions such as the Heaviside function.
- The function $f(t)$ that takes the value $1$ when $t$ is rational and takes the value $0$ when $t$ is irrational is an example of a function that is not Riemann integrable, but *is* Lebesgue integrable. The integral of this $f$ on any interval is equal to $0$. I'm sure your high school teacher didn't spend much time on "weird" functions like these!

Notice that this theorem only says that $F'(t)$ exists and is equal to $f(t)$ for *almost all* $t$. ["Almost all"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) is a technical term. Roughly speaking, a statement holds for almost all $t \in (a, b)$ if the probability of the statement being true for a $t$ selected uniformly at random from $(a, b)$ is equal to $1$.

In the case where $f$ is the Heaviside step function, the primitive $F$ is differentiable at every $t$ except for $t = 0$. So the primitive $F$ is differentiable at *almost all* $t$.